# How to find or trace child click in tableviewrow (Titanium Studio)

Tags: iphone

I am new to Titanium Studio. I'm working on table view. I've added some Image views and Labels in a tableviewrow. Can I add eventlistener to the each children in table view row. And I'm adding rows to the table inside a loop. Below is my code:

```
var tweetsTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({height:360, width: 306, top: 58, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderColor: '#C8C8C8',borderWidth:2, zIndex: -1});
var tweetsArray = [];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({contentHeight: 'auto', width: 320,top:0, selectionStyle : Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE});

    var my = Ti.UI.createView({ top:10,width:300,height:100 });

    var accImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({Image: Ti.App.logoImage,width:50,height:50,left:10,top:5,borderRadius:4});

    var addPlus = Ti.UI.createLabel({text:"+",color:"orange", font:{fontSize:18},borderWidth:0,bottom:5,right:20, width: 20, height: 20 });

    var addMinus = Ti.UI.createLabel({text:"-",color:"orange", font:{fontSize:18},borderWidth:0,bottom:5,right:10, width: 20, height: 20 });

    my.add(accImage);
    my.add(addPlus);
    my.add(addMinus);

    row.add(my);
    tweetsArray.push(row);

    accImage.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert(i);
    }

    addPlus.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert(i);
    }

    addMinus.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert(i);
    }

}
```

I want to add event listener for accImage,addPlus,addMinus. But i unable to find click event of accImage,addPlus,addMinus separately. If i add event listener inside for loop it working, but the last row children only working. If i click first row addPlus, then the last row addPlus is working.

How can i add event listener dynamically for each children in each row.
Can any one please..

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do?  Having the listener in the loop looks wrong from what I've experienced in the past, but I can't be sure.  Since you are showing you just want to alert, it is hard to understand if you can't have a general listener for all the rows and just have decision logic in the listener that takes a branching action.

Comment: i just added alert for to identify listener. i unable to maintain dynamic listener

Comment: That is why it is hard to understand what you are trying to do.  Once you successfully identify the click, what would you do?  I'm assuming you would take a specific action against a specific tweet?  What value would identify a specific tweet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. My code is below:

```
var tweetsTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({height:360, width: 306, top: 58, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderColor: '#C8C8C8',borderWidth:2, zIndex: -1});
var tweetsArray = [];

// response contains array of contents. The following loop will runs up to response length

for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
{

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({contentHeight: 'auto', width: 320,top:0, selectionStyle : Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE});

    var my = Ti.UI.createView({ top:10,width:300,height:100 });

    var accImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({Image: Ti.App.logoImage,width:50,height:50,left:10,top:5,borderRadius:4});

    var addPlus = Ti.UI.createLabel({text:"+",color:"orange", font:{fontSize:18},borderWidth:0,bottom:5,right:20, width: 20, height: 20 });

    var addMinus = Ti.UI.createLabel({text:"-",color:"orange", font:{fontSize:18},borderWidth:0,bottom:5,right:10, width: 20, height: 20 });

    my.add(accImage);
    my.add(addPlus);
    my.add(addMinus);

    row.add(my);
    tweetsArray.push(row);

    //find whether event from accImage
    tweetsArray[i].children[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        imageFunction(response[e.index]['name']);
    });

    //find whether event from addPlus
    tweetsArray[i].children[1].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        plusFunction(response[e.index]['name']);
    });

    //find whether event from addMinus
    tweetsArray[i].children[2].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        minusFunction(response[e.index]['name']);
    });

}
```

I hope it will useful to some one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe your requirement is better suited using the example source code from Titanium Mobile's Kitchen Sink example (Table_view_layout2.js).  You can get the source for this inside the Titanium Studio IDE, there is a Samples section on the lower left where you can import the code.  In the code, navigate to Resources/iu/common/baseui/table_view_layout2.js to view or debug the example and see how it operates.  Make sure you get an updated one, since it looks like they have updated this code since version 2.0.0 was released.

It has a single event listener for the table and queries the source of the click.  The example shows an image, which is using a view rather than image view and several labels.  The listener determines the item that was clicked and displays it on the screen.  You can change that logic to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.  Similar to your code, they build the table using a for loop, so you can draw some parallels to your code.

For the specific Tweet id, you can place that in your row variable.

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
 contentHeight: 'auto', 
 width: 320,
 top:0, 
 selectionStyle : Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE,
 myTweetId: tweetId // <================= Add here
});
```

Then in your listener logic, you can query the e.rowData.myTweetid to find which tweet you need to modify.

Just to clarify, the listeners would reduce down to a single listener on the table's (tweetsTable) 'click' event and it would be defined outside of the loop logic you have.

I didn't really want to paste this in here, but this is the code in the file.  You could have just looked it up in the free source code I mentioned as well as being able to run through it with the debugger.

```
function tv_layout2() {
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
    win.barColor = '#385292';

    if (Ti.Platform.osname !== 'mobileweb') {

        //
        // CREATE SEARCH BAR
        //
        var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
            barColor:'#385292',
            showCancel:false
        });
        search.addEventListener('change', function(e)
        {
            e.value; // search string as user types
        });
        search.addEventListener('return', function(e)
        {
            search.blur();
        });
        search.addEventListener('cancel', function(e)
        {
            search.blur();
        });
    }

    var tableView;
    var data = [];

    // create first row
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    row.backgroundColor = '#576996';
    row.selectedBackgroundColor = '#385292';
    row.height = 40;
    var clickLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text:'Click different parts of the row',
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center',
        font:{fontSize:14},
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto'
    });
    row.className = 'header';
    row.add(clickLabel);
    data.push(row);

    // when you click the header, scroll to the bottom
    row.addEventListener('click',function()
    {
        tableView.scrollToIndex(40,{animated:true,position:Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewScrollPosition.TOP});
    });

    // create update row (used when the user clicks on the row)
    function createUpdateRow(text)
    {
        var updateRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
        updateRow.backgroundColor = '#13386c';
        updateRow.selectedBackgroundColor = '#13386c';

        // add custom property to identify this row
        updateRow.isUpdateRow = true;
        var updateRowText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#fff',
            font:{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'},
            text:text,
            width:'auto',
            height:'auto'
        });
        updateRow.className = 'updated_row';
        updateRow.add(updateRowText);
        return updateRow;
    }
    // create a var to track the active row
    var currentRow = null;
    var currentRowIndex = null;

    // create the rest of the rows
    for (var c=1;c<50;c++)
    {
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
        row.selectedBackgroundColor = '#fff';
        row.height = 100;
        row.className = 'datarow';
        row.clickName = 'row';

        var photo = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundImage:'/images/custom_tableview/user.png',
            top:5,
            left:10,
            width:50,
            height:50,
            clickName:'photo'
        });
        row.add(photo);


        var user = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#576996',
            font:{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold', fontFamily:'Arial'},
            left:70,
            top:2,
            height:30,
            width:200,
            clickName:'user',
            text:'Fred Smith '+c
        });

        row.filter = user.text;
        row.add(user);

        var fontSize = 16;
        if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android') {
            fontSize = 14;
        }
        var comment = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#222',
            font:{fontSize:fontSize,fontWeight:'normal', fontFamily:'Arial'},
            left:70,
            top:21,
            height:50,
            width:200,
            clickName:'comment',
            text:'Got some fresh fruit, conducted some business, took a nap'
        });
        row.add(comment);

        var calendar = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundImage:'/images/custom_tableview/eventsButton.png',
            bottom:2,
            left:70,
            width:32,
            clickName:'calendar',
            height:32
        });
        row.add(calendar);

        var button = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundImage:'/images/custom_tableview/commentButton.png',
            top:35,
            right:5,
            width:36,
            clickName:'button',
            height:34
        });
        row.add(button);

        var date = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#999',
            font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'normal', fontFamily:'Arial'},
            left:105,
            bottom:5,
            height:20,
            width:100,
            clickName:'date',
            text:'posted on 3/11'
        });
        row.add(date);

        data.push(row);
    }


    //
    // create table view (
    //
    if (Ti.Platform.osname !== 'mobileweb') {
        tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
            data:data,
            search:search,
            filterAttribute:'filter',
            backgroundColor:'white'
        });
    } else {
        tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
            data:data,
            filterAttribute:'filter',
            backgroundColor:'white'
        });
    }

    tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        Ti.API.info('table view row clicked - source ' + e.source);
        // use rowNum property on object to get row number
        var rowNum = e.index;
        var updateRow;
        if (Ti.Platform.osname !== 'mobileweb') {
            updateRow = createUpdateRow('You clicked on the '+e.source.clickName);
            tableView.updateRow(rowNum,updateRow,{animationStyle:Titanium.UI.iPhone.RowAnimationStyle.LEFT});
        } else {
            updateRow = createUpdateRow('Row clicked');
            tableView.updateRow(rowNum,updateRow);
        }
    });

    win.add(tableView);

    return win;
};

module.exports = tv_layout2;
```