# get row data when corresponding row is clicked in tableview

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new to titanium. I am creating a custom table view with row. I have added 4 views in a row. Each corresponding view has label --->> Check In time, Check out time,Note and Time.  Check In and Check Out gives time for the task.  Note is to add note and Time to display difference in Check In and Check Out Time. I want to update Note for particular task in database accoding to current Check In time. I am not getting the way to capture the text on current Check In Time Label when that particular click of row. If i get the check in time then i will update the corresponding row in database according to current check in time.

Here is my code.

function set(date,intime,outtime)
{
            var date1=date;

```
        var section = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection();
         row1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({layout:"horizontal"});


        inview=Ti.UI.createView({
               width:"25%",
        });

        inlabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({
             text:intime,
            font:{fontSize:13}

        });
        inview.add(inlabel);



        outview=Ti.UI.createView({
             width:"25%",

        });

        outlabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:outtime,
            font:{fontSize:13}
        });

        outview.add(outlabel);

        inview.addEventListener('click',function(e){


               // Ti.API.info(';',e.row1.rowID);                

                var picker=Ti.UI.createPicker();
                picker.showTimePickerDialog({

                    callback: function(e){

                          if(e.cancel)
                          {
                             Ti.API.info('user canceled dialog');
                          }
                          else{

                                Ti.API.info('user selected date'+e.value);

                               var d=new Date(e.value);                                     
                               var time=String.formatTime(d);                                            

                               var newintime=d.getTime();

                                Ti.API.info(':'+time);                

                             //   var total=calculatetime(newintime,currouttime);

                             //   timelabel.text=total;

                                inlabel.text=time;                                                                        
                               //updateintime(date1,inlabel.text);



                          }
                    }

                });

        });


        outview.addEventListener('click',function(e){

                var picker=Ti.UI.createPicker();
                picker.showTimePickerDialog({

                    callback: function(e){

                          if(e.cancel)
                          {
                             Ti.API.info('user canceled dialog');
                          }
                          else{

                                Ti.API.info('user selected date'+e.value);

                                 var d=new Date(e.value);
                                 var time=String.formatTime(d);

                                 var newoutime=d.getTime();

                                 Ti.API.info(''+newoutime);      

                              //     var total=calculatetime(currintime,newoutime);

                                // timelabel.text=total;                                

                                 outlabel.text=time;
                             //   updateoutime(date1,outlabel.text);

                          }
                    }

                });

        });



        var timeview=Ti.UI.createView({
              width:"25%",

        });


         var intime=parseInt(inlabel.text);
         var outime=parseInt(outlabel.text);

         var time=intime-outime;

        var timelabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({

              text:time,              
              font:{fontSize:13}
        });

        timeview.add(timelabel);



        var noteview=Ti.UI.createImageView({                
            image:'TaskNote.png',
            width:"15%",

        });             


        noteview.addEventListener('click',function(e){

                    var tasknotewindow=Ti.UI.createWindow({
                    backgroundColor:'white',
                    layout:'vertical',
                    url:'TimeTracker/tasknote.js'

                });

                tasknotewindow.starttime=e.inlabel.text;

                tasknotewindow.open();
        });                         

        var taskview=Ti.UI.createView({
            width:"25%",

        });

        tasklabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({
             text:"Click",
             font:{fontSize:13},

        });


        //create window for task management
        var taskmanagewindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                    backgroundColor: 'white', layout: 'vertical',
                    url:'TimeTracker/task.js'
        }); 


        //Task Dialog Box
        taskoptionBox=Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({                            
                title:'Task',
                options:arrtaskname,
                buttonNames:['Cancel'],                     
         });

         taskoptionBox.addEventListener('click',function(e){                
             tasklabel.text= arrtaskname[e.index];                   
         });


        tasklabel.addEventListener('click',function(e){                 
                taskoptionBox.show();               
        });


        taskview.add(tasklabel);

        row1.add(inview);
        row1.add(outview);
        row1.add(timeview);
        row1.add(noteview);
        row1.add(taskview);         

        section.add(row1);
        data.push(section);
        table.setData(data);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question/answer.  Perhaps you will be able to accomplish your objective using this.  I think you are both trying the same thing.

[How to find or trace child click in tableviewrow (Titanium Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776584/how-to-find-or-trace-child-click-in-tableviewrow-titanium-studio/12784096#comment17281686_12784096)

This is how I've always accomplished this:

```
row1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
  layout:"horizontal",
  myval: intime // <=== Add your value here that you want to query for.
});
...
inlabel=Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text:intime,
  font:{fontSize:13}
});
inview.add(inlabel);
...

tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert(e.rowData.myval);
});
...

// This section seems jumbled.  Should be something along the lines of the following...
// You have:
// section.add(row1);
// data.push(section);
// table.setData(data);
// Change to:
data.push(row1);
table.setData(data);
section.add(table);
```

Originally, I thought you wanted to manipulate the label inside the row, based on your comment that seems different now.

Comment: I not geetting it... the link here gives hint of taking childern property of the array .... but my IDE is not giving me the childern porperty

Comment: The IDE doesn't always expose all functionality of the objects.  If you are looking for the 'intellisense' to kick in, it might not for that functionality.  Try experimenting with his code and see if it just works without depending on the IDE to write it for you.

Comment: Hi, Martin Thanks for help!! my query is different... i have created custom row having one view and 4 lables... i want to find the text of first lable(check in) when i click on any row in table..

Comment: Hi, Martin .. I want to get the text of the first label.... when i click on row in tableview...

Comment: Why does it matter that the text comes from the first label or the rowData?  If you put that value in the myval property, you'd have the value when you click on the row as demonstrated.

Comment: I changed the example to hopefully make it more clear on what is happening.

Comment: Weird.  Post your answer when you figure it out.